# 3 lights controlled by 3 switches - convert one for ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, switch

How do I rewire a light receptacle within a 4-way switch to accommodate a ceiling fan?  We have a basement with three lights controlled by three different switches in the basement.  All three lights turn on/off at the same time using any of the three switches.  I want to convert one of the lights to a ceiling fan, without having all of the other lights turn on.  I do not need to control the fan with any of the switches, only need the fan wires hot so I can power the fan and use a remote. I want to leave the functionality of the three switches to control the remaining two lights if possible.

Pictures below. All walls are finished drywall.

Switch 1:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Switch 2:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Switch 3:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that "thoughts and advice" on a vague post like this aren't really a good fit for our format. A specific question that can elicit specific answers are what we shoot for. This just invites discussion and that's off topic here. Please [edit] your question to actually _ask a question_ (like, "How do I rewire so I can...?"), and I'm sure you'll get good answers. Also, pictures of the wiring in the switches and the ceiling would be very helpful in helping us design an answer to help you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Sure can, just to clarify...  you want photos of the switch boxes, correct?  Do you want the switches pulled out as well?

Comment: Yes extend the switches out of the box so we can see the number of cables and conductors present in the boxes. Also, is the basement finished (drywall or whatever) or are the structure and wiring exposed?

Comment: Probably couldn't upload directly because the pictures were too big. That is an extremely common problem - as far as I can tell SE hasn't expanded allowable image size in a long time, if ever. I have created a workaround - see https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/image-shrinking-upload

Comment: @philstromsoe -- can you get us photos looking squarely into the backs of the boxes please?

Comment: Added photos to each switch section in post.  Switches 1 and 2 are both 2 gang boxes/switches.  One switch for the lights in basement and the other for other independent lights - Switch 1 box for stair lights and switch 2 box for back patio light.  Switch 3 is a single gang/switch for the basement lights only.  Hopes this helps and thanks all for looking and replying.